# Electron dialog showing 'Electron' in app name instead of the actual app name

Tags: electron

Electron dialog showing 'Electron' in app name  instead of the actual app name in `package.json`

Using `"electron": "7.1.2"`

My main JS

```
//main.js

const pdfMaxSave = exports.pdfMaxSave = ()=>{
  let options={
      title: 'Save to pdf',
      buttonLabel:'save pdf',
       filters: [
        { name: 'pdf', extensions: ['pdf'] },
         ]
  }
  dialog.showSaveDialog(mainWindow,options).then(response=>{
        console.log(response.filePath);
});
}
```

> [image: When the dialog appears it has '**Electron**' as the app name.]

Comment: Is this the result after packing the app?

Comment: i haven't packaged it yet

Comment: before showing the dialog, the app's name is showing correctly as name at pakcage.json?

Comment: yes it shows correctly but once i open the dialog it changes to `Electron`

Comment: How about closing the dialog

Comment: When i cancel or close `Electron` remains until you maximize or minimise

Comment: What do you mean by cancel or close Electron

Comment: So maybe, you mean. When you are going to close the Electron main app

Comment: Then the dialog still remains until the app is maximize or minimise?

Comment: when i cancel or when the operation its supposed to do is done which in this case its the `console.log` sorry for the mistyping

Comment: Thats the behavior currently

Comment: Confirmed the behavior doesn't persist after creating executable. thanks @tpikachu